# Error While Trying to get UsedRange from Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

Trying to get the active range of cells in Excel.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
Dim xApp As New Excel.Application
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rng As Excel.Range

ws = xApp.Workbooks.Open(oFile.FullName).Worksheets(1)
rng = ws.UsedRange
```

The Error I get says:
`The embedded interop type 'UsedRange' does not contain a definition for 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet' since it was not used in the compiled assembly. Consider casting to object or changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property to true.`

Comment: what version of excel interop you're using?

Comment: I just tried your code and it worked fine... I'm using 14.0

Comment: That may be the problem. When I was including the resources, the only one on the list was 14.0. however, I'm using office 2007, which is 12.0. gonna try finding the resource files for that...

Comment: That appears to be the problem. I went into the com section and found excel interop 12.0, and it found the range fine. I wonder what version of excel the client is using...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding reference to latest version of Excel Interop, that seems to be a problem.

Comment: I just get `Worksheet is a type and cannot be used as an expression`

Comment: Figured out I was using interop 14.0, and Office 2007 which is interop 12.0. I added the 12.0 interop from the com section and it started working good.